# Package 'gnome-control-center' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, dpkg, software-center

I am unable to install gnome-control-center. I removed it earlier due to some reasons. Whenever I try to install it, I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-control-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gnome-control-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  gnome-control-center-data

E: Package 'gnome-control-center' has no installation candidate
```

Everything worked fine until I to installed samba server which failed I don't know why but with this message `dpkg is locked`. I uninstalled it and did this `sudo apt autoremove`. After that I tried to reinstall it but I get the same error but with `samba` in place of `gnome-control-center`. So, I manually deleted all the files for samba as indicated by `whereis samba`. After that this trouble started.

UPDATE:

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

UPDATE 2:
Output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic restricted
# deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates restricted
# deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[gnome-control-center](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gnome-control-center) package exists in [main](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories#Main) repository of Ubuntu. To enable it, you can run either of the below three commands:

- [`add-apt-repository`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html) with `main`:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository main
  ```
- [`add-apt-repository`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html) with full address of archive:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main"
  ```
- Editing [SourcesList](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SourcesList) with [`tee`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html):

  ```
  echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
  ```

Once enabled, try installing gnome-control-center again.